# Difficulty structuring a relationship between a parent model and multiple polymorphic children models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, polymorphic-associations, ruby-on-rails-4

- I have `User` that `has_one :profile`.
- I have `Profile` that has some attributes that every single profile will have in common.
- I want some `Users` to have a `Sub_profile` of either `Coach_profile` or `Student_profile`.

I intend on using a polymorphic relationship between `Profile` and these `Sub_profiles` to allow each `User` to have their basic `Profile` then have their appropriate `Sub_profile`.

*This is where I'm getting tied in knots.*

I'm having a challenging time figuring out where the `belongs_to`, `has_one :profile`, `as: :sub_profile` `polymorphic: true`, and `dependent: :destroy` methods all belong.

At this point, someone who understands how to build this type of solution would be able to write up the relationships - but I feel I need to explain my (flawed) reasoning for building it the way I did so someone can help me understand why what I did was wrong.

**My problem:**

It is also important to note, just in case it isn't obvious, that the below code structure does not result in code that actually works as desired (described above).  I am having errors like:

```
> Coach_profile.create
RuntimeError: Circular dependency detected while autoloading constant Coach_profile
```

And trying something like:

```
> user.profile.build_coach_profile
```

results in `undefined method build_coach_profile for profile`

**The reasoning behind my code:**

The way I have my code built now, I cannot figure out how to `build_sub_profiles` or `build_coach_profile` (as an example) because the way I designed my relationships does not allow for that.

- I want my `Profiles` to `belongs_to :sub_profile, polymorphic: true, dependent: :destroy` because I want there to be a `sub_profile_id` in my `profile` table so I can

  - reference `profile.sub_profile`
  - have different types of `sub_profiles`
  - destroy associated `sub_profiles` when a `profile` is destroyed
- I want my `sub_profiles` (`coach` and `student` profile) to `has_one :profile, as: :sub_profile`

  - so each of my `sub_profile` types can belong to a `profile` via the `sub_profile_id` and `sub_profile_type` fields of my `profile` table.

user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  has_one :profile

end
```

profile.rb

```
#  id               :integer          not null, primary key
#  user_id          :integer
#  first_name       :string(255)      not null
#  middle_name      :string(255)
#  last_name        :string(255)      not null
#  phone_number     :integer
#  birth_date       :date             not null
#  created_at       :datetime
#  updated_at       :datetime
#  sub_profile_id   :integer
#  sub_profile_type :string(255)
#

class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :sub_profile, polymorphic: true, dependent: :destroy

    validates_presence_of :first_name, :last_name, :birth_date
    validates_length_of :phone_number, {is: 10 || 0}
end
```

coach_profile.rb

```
#  id             :integer          not null, primary key
#  coaching_since :date
#  type_of_coach  :string(255)
#  bio            :text
#  created_at     :datetime
#  updated_at     :datetime
#

class CoachProfile < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :profile, as: :sub_profile
end
```

student_profile.rb

```
#  id                     :integer          not null, primary key
#  playing_since          :date
#  competition_level      :string(255)
#  learn_best_by          :string(255)
#  desirable_coach_traits :text
#  goals                  :text
#  bio                    :text
#  created_at             :datetime
#  updated_at             :datetime
#

class StudentProfile < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :profile, as: :sub_profile
end
```

I am approaching something incorrectly here.  How do I properly set up a polymorphic relationship between several `sub_profiles` and a parent `profile`?

Comment: simply reverse belongs_to has_one between Profile and SubProfile and you'll figure out everything else in minutes.

Comment: I changed my sub profiles to read `belongs_to :profile, polymorphic: true` as opposed to the `has_one :profile, as: :sub_profile` and moved the `as: :sub_profile` part over to the has_one line within profile because it appears that I cannot use `as: :model` on a `belongs_to` call.

I then added `belongs_to :profile, as: :sub_profile` to my migrations for the sub_profiles.

I still get a circular dependency error when trying `Coach_profile.create`, I think I'm missing something still.  If you have any input it would be great, but I am going to keep digging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure the relationship is the problem here? You say you're calling `Coach_profile.create`, but rails class names are supposed to be like `CoachProfile` with no underscore, and it looks like yours is. Does `CoachProfile.create` give the same error?

You may just be confusing the Rails code that autoloads source files when you use them.

Also, it won't work to switch to Profile has_one :sub_profile as Michael suggested because it wouldn't be able to figure out which table to look for the sub profile in. In a polymorphic relationship, the type column is on the same table as the foreign key.

Comment: CoachProfile.create does not give the same error.  In fact, it creates the object.  Now to figure out how to properly call something along the lines of profile.build_coach_profile.

Comment: You could write a build_coach_profile method yourself; it won't be generated for you (see [auto-generated methods](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html)). You'll need to just do `profile.sub_profile = CoachProfile.build`

Comment: You were totally right - thank you for the auto-generated methods link (some Rails 'magic' I hadn't thought of just yet).  Now for the joy of wrapping controllers around all this - once again, however, probably easier than I think.